# multiple conditions with calculation in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a situation where I need to calculate the local time based on the Pacific time zone column.

sample data

```
Pacific_AM_PM   timezone    
     8           Pacific               
     11          Eastern                
     20          Central
```

the logic is that,

if timezone= Pacific, then local_time: 8+0=8

if timezone= Eastern, then local_time: 11+3=14

only 4 conditions total: Pacific, Eastern, mountain, central

expect output

```
Pacific_AM_PM   timezone    adjust_hour  local_time
     8           Pacific        0           8
     11          Eastern        3           14
     20          Central        2           22
```

I attempt to use numpy.where to set the conditions, but i don't know how. I'm not limited to use numpy.

Comment: Have you considered assignment using `.loc`? Edit: is there a restriction that forces you to use `np.where`?

Comment: For posterity, look into pytz. This can help you do this easily.

Comment: @TomasFarias I'm not limited to use numpy, please advice on solutions.

Comment: Use `np.select` to set the 4 conditions and then the 4 operations

Comment: Am I missing something or if you already have the `adjust_hour` column why don't you just use addition here.

Comment: Does your sample data contain the adjust_hour column, or just `Pacific_AM_PM` and `timezone`?

Comment: please see my updated edit

Comment: Oh, then just add the two columns. `df.Pacific_AM_PM + df.adjust_hour`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Just add the columns

```
df['local_time'] = df.Pacific_AM_PM + df.adjust_hour
```

### numpy.select

You can specify a list of conditions and the corresponding value to use when the first `True` is found in the conditions. Since your conditions are mutually exclusive, order isn't very important in `conds` or `choice`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

conds = [df.timezone == 'Pacific', df.timezone == 'Eastern', df.timezone == 'Central']
choice = [df.Pacific_AM_PM, df.Pacific_AM_PM+3, df.Pacific_AM_PM+2]
df['local_time']= np.select(conds, choice)
```

Output:

```
   Pacific_AM_PM timezone  local_time
0              8  Pacific           8
1             11  Eastern          14
2             20  Central          22
```

---

### Series.map

Specify a dictionary that maps the timezones to values and then just add them to the other column.

```
dct = {'Pacific': 0, 'Eastern': 3, 'Central': 2}
df['local_time'] = df.timezone.map(dct) + df.Pacific_AM_PM
```

Output:

```
   Pacific_AM_PM timezone  local_time
0              8  Pacific           8
1             11  Eastern          14
2             20  Central          22
```

Comment: Why don't you just add by the adjust hour column?  It seems like it's already in his dataframe

Comment: That's true, but I interpreted the first line of the question "I need to calculate the local time based on the Pacific time zone column" as meaning there was actually no adjust_hour column in the real dataframe and it was just added to the example. 

If it's truly just addition then I'll delete.

Comment: @ALollz,sorry for any confusion, please see my updated sample and expected dataframe